# Way to dismiss tag hover popup after you've moused over it

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips

Fairly often, tag hover popups refuse to go away when I move my mouse off the tag or the tag moves due to some other event: (**Edit:** When it's been moused over)

[image: Stuck tag hover popup]

I'd certainly like this to be fixed, but it seems to me it'll probably happen occasionally anyway. I currently use Firefox 6. **Edit:** By "fixed" I now mean for the popup to disappear if the tag does, like when I inline edit, as in the screenshot.

My real request is an 'x', perhaps in the upper or lower right corner, allowing me to close the popup:

[image]

This method is just a suggestion, but I would really like some way to dismiss the popup, as I often want to be able to read or type something underneath it<strike>, and as things are now I have to navigate away from the page and return</strike>.

**Edit:** The first answer points out this will happen if you accidentally or intentionally move the mouse over the tag, and that moving over any tag should clear it.

This will still often require that I scroll elsewhere on the page to remove it (for example, when I edit a question with inline-editing, as in the screenshot, when it fails to disappear with the tag).

<strike>Also, are there any situations where there is only one tag on a page? In that case, you would still need to navigate away once you've moused-over the hover popup.</strike>It appears that most of the time, mousing over the same tag will work. So, as long as there is any tag on the page you won't have to navigate away, but inline editing still makes this a pain as it moves the tags. I also still occasionally am unable to make it disappear by mousing over the any tag, but this is a somewhat separate issue.

**Final Edit:** Fixed as of 2011-8-14.

**Post-Final Edit:** Occasionally, the popup still doesn't disappear when I move the mouse away from it. However, so far, moving the mouse back over it and away again has always cleared it.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) to learn what upvotes and downvotes mean on Meta.

Comment: @Cody Thanks, I didn't realize something so fundamental would be different.

Comment: I can't actually repro this bug report; the tag popups seem to close just fine for me. But I can't see anything *wrong* with the feature request of adding a close box to it. If you don't need to use it, then you won't use it. If you find yourself with it stuck on the screen and want to close it, then you can. It's a simple, consistent, and non-intrusive bit of UI. (Net score +0)

Comment: It's not really fundamental. Votes are the way we categorize content. When it comes to feature requests, ones that receive a lot of upvotes are more likely to be implemented. Conversely, ones with a lot of downvotes are less likely to be implemented. Same with bug reports; if you can't repro it or you don't think it's a real bug or you don't think it's worth fixing, you might downvote. Makes a lot of sense to me. The issue arises from people taking downvotes personally, which is really invalid either here *or* on the main site.

Comment: It may be browser specific. If I mouse over a tag, then mouse over the popup, then click "edit", the popup seems to always remain until I leave the page or mouseover another tag.

Comment: I can repro this on Firefox 3.6 for Vista: the popup won't close when I've moused over it. However, I don't have to navigate away from the page to get rid of the popup; hovering over _any_ tag (e.g. the one belonging to the popup) and moving away will do. But it's still annoying, so +1 for you. It seems indeed to be a recent change; it hasn't happened to me until recently. I liked the old behaviour much better.

Comment: @Hendrik Yeah, it really seems to be a problem primarily with inline editing (as the tag moves / disappears) or when there is a bug and it won't disappear at all. I seem to _sometimes_ be able to make it go away on the original tag, but not always. Perhaps I'm mousing back over the popup without noticing?

Comment: @agf: Maybe it's different while editing inline; so far it only happened to me while browsing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a regression - the tag hover will now be dismissed on mouseout like it did previously.  This will be in the next build.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the code, the only time that this should happen is when you hover over a tag and the mouse moves over the resulting popup. Additionally, hovering over any tag again should remove the popup from the page without you needing to reload. It's hard to say if this is the intended behaviour, though.

If it is, I agree, there should be a way to close the popup. The popup should also be removed automatically when the tag it belongs to is removed from the page, like when you hover over a tag popup on your way to the edit link (which I assume is what happened in your screenshot).

If not, the solution would be just to have the `#tag-menu` `mouseleave` handler call the `mouseleave` handler already delegated to `.post-tag:not(.user-tag)` after resetting the hover flag.

Comment: It frequently (I don't know about always) stays around when I inline edit. It sounds right to me that this only happens when I've moved the mouse over the popup.

Answer (score 2):

Using Safari 5.1, the pop-up stays open when I hover the mouse other the pop-up. The pop-up didn't work in this way, previously.
It doesn't go away, even if I click with the left mouse button on the window, as it is visible in this screenshot. (The blue area is because the browser selected the area when I clicked two times in row.)

[image: screenshot]

A close button would be helpful, in such cases.

Comment: So, it doesn't stay if you just mouse over the popup after mousing over the tag?

Comment: Normally, the pop-up closes when I move away the mouse; this is the behavior I have always seen with all the browsers I used, since the tag pop-up has been implemented.

Comment: Even if you mouse over the popup too, not just the tag?

Comment: Uhmmm… It doesn't go away, if I hover the mouse over the pop-up. It must be a recent change.

Comment: Ok. That seems to jive with what me and the other answerer were saying. Good to have other confirmation.